# Instance of a class expected, not the class itself Error

Tags: pycharm, python-3.6, instance

The code that I have wrote works but I get an warning error in Pycharm that states that it expected an instance of a class to be passed not the class itself. It states that this may be intentional however it can cause subtle bugs.

Without me passing it through 'User' it throws an error..What can I do to fix this so it does not show an error?

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay

    def email(self):
        return '{}.{}@company.com'.format(self.first, self.last)

    def fullname(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.last)


user1 = User


def add_user():
    first = input('First name: ')
    user1.first = first
    last = input('Last name: ')
    user1.last = last
    pay = int(input('Pay: '))
    user1.pay = pay


add_user()
print(user1.fullname(User))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `user1 = User` asigns a reference to the User *class* to the variable user1.

What you want is create an *instance* of the user class, so you need to change that line to

`user1 = User("FirstName", "LastName", 42)`

since you require 3 parameters to be passed to the constructor(`__init__`).

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes I can manually add them but my intention is to utilize a function to do that for me.

Comment: If that is the case your init should be `def __init__(self):`, not taking any arguments and then just create the initial member values like this: `self.first self.last = str()` and `self.pay=-1`. Make sure they are falsey values you can interpret easily.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you for your help mate appreciate it

Comment: Anytime! We all started out as novices :)